# On synology dsm, add a specific nginx config to a specific virtual host

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect, synology

On a synology dsm we use an nginx webstation. On this webstation we have (several) virtual hosts. One example is that we wish to redirect all incoming traffic on port "282" (which is beyond the router incoming at port 80 with a specific domain) to another website. (Basically the same but rather using https, and port 443).

We selected our root, and tested that loading the page does indeed load the `index.html` from root. With an apache server we could add an `.htaccess` to that root folder.

But what is the structure that can be done for nginx? If I hunt the configuration I notice the server is using:

```
server {

    listen      282 default_server;
    listen      [::]:282 default_server;

    server_name _;

    root    "/volume1/web/example.app";
    index    index.html  index.htm  index.cgi  index.php  index.php5 ;
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 500 501 502 503 504 505 @error_page;

    location @error_page {
        root /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page;
        rewrite ^ /$status.html break;
    }

    location ^~ /_webstation_/ {
        alias    /var/packages/WebStation/target/error_page/;
    }

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/ecd72a1b-c840-494f-8d6a-a837da4e0d94/user.conf*;

}
```

However modifying the config files directly doesn't work - synology dsm will overwrite those on restart.

So what is the canonical way to add a custom configuration to the webstation? Or better - how can I tell the virtual host to not just load the page but rather just be a redirect?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change this config, but you can extend it by using the mentioned user config file at the bottom. In your example `/usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/ecd72a1b-c840-494f-8d6a-a837da4e0d94/user.conf`. You can add all required changes to this file which will not be changed/removed when the Synology reboots (or Webstation restarts).

To test your changes you can reload the nginx configuration via `sudo nginx -s reload` from a ssh session.